# ActivityManager <user-permission> permission not working

Tags: android, android-permissions

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="per.sainik.activity"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<user-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" >
</user-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".LogViewActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

and

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class LogViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplication()
            .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Log.v("LOG_SERVICE", activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0)
            .toString());
}
```

}

It's getting exception , named :

```
01-05 14:55:05.207: E/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{per.sainik.activity/per.sainik.activity.LogViewActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getTasks() from pid=334, uid=10037 requires android.permission.GET_TASKS
```

Getting permission problem. Any Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: It should be `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have misspelled the permission. The Exact permission is,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" >
</uses-permission>
```

not,

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" >
</user-permission>
```

Comment: but still issues are there for android 4.0

Comment: @ParthAnjaria what issues are you talking about ?

Answer (score 3):

You have misspelled the word `<uses-permission >` as `<user-permission >` .